# My app does not get any notification when power saving mode is active

Tags: android, notifications, samsung-mobile

My app does not get notifications when device power saving mode enabled. It usually happens on Samsung devices. What can be the problem and are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: in power saving mode your mobile restricts the background services that why notification is not working. try to use Firebase JobDispatcher

Comment: System restrict background apps in power saver mode.

Comment: Hmm this is because i have a service working on background. When i disable it, all will become normal?

Comment: @SarathKumar when i switch to firebase, this problem does not occur anymore?